# What is the logic is used in this program

Tags: c

A 5 digit positive number is entered by user.how to calculate the sum of the Digits entered by the user with the help of function?

Comment: You must try to do your homework on your own. If you are learning programming the you cannot run away from programs.

Comment: If you are looking for some help. Here's a link that may help you - 
[C program to find sum of digits using recursion](http://www.codeforwin.in/2016/03/c-program-to-calculate-sum-of-digits-using-recursion.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for code is not the purpose of this site. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We beginners should help each other.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int digits_sum( unsigned int value )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    do { sum += value % Base; } while ( value /= Base );

    return sum;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int value = 12345;

    printf( "The sum of digits of number %u is %u\n", value, digits_sum( value ) ); 

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The sum of digits of number 12345 is 15
```

The logic is simple. To get the last digit of a number you should apply operator `%`. Then you need to divide the number by 10 that in the next step to get the digit before the last and so on.

Comment: @TZHX  Answering questions I have a practice. :) In fact it is my own homework.